# Ruby on Rails MSSQL TinyTds::Error: Invalid object name after creating a table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sql-server, ruby

We are using MS-SQL database with gem `tiny_tds` as an database adapter.

We used to have a class `Document`, that had it's table `documents`. Then we introduced new class `ClientDocument`that was inheriting from `Document` and shared the db table.

`class Document < ApplicationRecord; end`

`class ClientDocument < Document; end`

We decided to move `ClientDocument` to its own table, therefore we simply created a migration and changed the inheritance of `ClientDocument`.

`class ClientDocument < ApplicationRecord; end`

If I now query `ClientDocument` on the database I will get an error, **however** if I create a new database, seed it, it works perfectly fine as desired. Does MS-SQL somehow cache its tables?

This is an output from the console if I query on an old database that "remembers" 1 table for 2 classes.

````
[13] pry(main)> ClientDocument.first
  ClientDocument Load (3.6ms)  EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT  [client_documents].* FROM [client_documents]  ORDER BY [client_documents].[id] ASC OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT @0 ROWS ONLY', N'@0 int', @0 = 1  [["LIMIT", nil]]
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: TinyTds::Error: Invalid object name 'client_documents'.: EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT  [client_documents].* FROM [client_documents]  ORDER BY [client_documents].[id] ASC OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT @0 ROWS ONLY', N'@0 int', @0 = 1
from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-5.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver/database_statements.rb:405:in `each'
Caused by TinyTds::Error: Invalid object name 'client_documents'.
from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-5.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver/database_statements.rb:405:in `each'
```
````

Comment: `rails db` should start your database client with the same same connection as your rails app. I would'nt touch sql-server with a 10 foot pole but you should be able to query the schema with something like `SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`.